# How to add space above video viewer

Tags: html, css

Here is the link to the page in question:

http://ollapodridawhatuneeda.com/video_viewer2.html

I want space above the video viewer screen, but so far adding margin or padding to the various containers has only resulted in pushing the entire content div down.  I want to keep it blue above the video viewer, not white.  thus far I have only accomplished pushing the container down while leaving a white band above it, which is not the effect I want.

Any ideas?

Barry Glick

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, a _specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: Why is this question on hold? It's about HTML/CSS, you just look at his page and use the browser inspector to work on the source.

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve your task is you can add:

```
padding-top: 100px;
```

for the `<div id="content">`, so your new CSS would look like:

```
#content {
    width: 960px;
    height: 1000px;
    background: #9CC;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 100px;
}
```

This will push the video container down.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible methods, depending where you want the distance (just try it):

1.) Add `margin: 100px;` (or whatever value) to `#videoContainer` (will add *above* the light-blue area)

2.) Or add `padding-top: 100px;` to `#content` (will add *inside* the light-blue area)